# how old are Inee and Imee now?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Inee and Imee are twins. Their mother is 28 years older than they are and 4 times as old as the sum of their ages. How old are Inee and Imee now?

Answer (score 2):

Let inee and imee are $y$ years old each now.

So, the current age of their mother is $y+28$ years

So we have $4(y+y)=y+28$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Mom's age:=$\;M\;$ , the twins' age:= $\;x\;$ , so we're given

$$M=x+28\;\;,\;\;\;M=4\cdot(2x)$$